# C# WPF - DataBinding RadioButtons not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have searched several tutorials and tried each option, but I cannot get my radio buttons to bind. When I try to compile the following code I get the error

> The resource "nullableBooleanConverter" could not be resolved

Here is what I currently have in XAML:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="grp_Option_1" Content="Yes" IsChecked="{Binding Path=OpstionSelected, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource nullableBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}" />
<RadioButton GroupName="grp_Option_2" Content="No" IsChecked="{Binding Path=OptionSelected, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource nullableBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}" />
```

My CS has

```
public bool OptionSelected
{
  get { return optionSelected; }
  set
  {
    optionSelected = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged("OptionSelected");
  }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
{
  if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    this.PropertyChanged(
    this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
}
```

Here is my converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool?), typeof(bool))]
public class SuccessConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool param = bool.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return !((bool)value ^ param);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool param = bool.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        return !((bool)value ^ param);
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the following lines in your `<Window.Resources>`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
            xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace: here.yournamespace.converts">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Converters:SuccessConverter x:Key="nullableBooleanConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I am getting an error: The URI "clr-namespace: WPF1.converts" is not a valid namespace identifier.

Comment: can you  poste  the namespace where your  SuccessConverter is defined

Comment: I figured it out based on your answer. My code works when I use xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:WPF1" where WPF1 is my namespace. I had to put it in the app.xaml section and the <Converters:SuccessConverter x:Key="nullableBooleanConverter" /> had to go under the application.resources section.